# Adding Multiple Wheres with Contains based on property decided at runtime in LINQ to Entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity

We've got a data object with multiple properties, mapped to the corresponding database table.

```
public partial class Sources
    {
        ...
        public string business_unit { get; set; }
        public string booking_point { get; set; }
        public string account { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

We're trying to filter the data set based on some runtime decided input, by creating a list for each selected dimensions. Note that leafList works as intended, as does dimLeaves. The problem is we're not able to use leafList to filter our main dataset.

As we can't mix DB with in-memory items, we're grabbing a partial dataset first and building our in-mem query. **The problem we're having is adding a Contains from a separate list, dependent on the runtime selected property.**

```
internal void GetSourceTotal(Int16 fiscal_year, Byte fiscal_month, Byte version)
        {

        using (DataContext db = new DataContext(AppEnvironment.DirectConnectionString))
        {
            var values = db.GetTable<Sources>();

            // full dataset to copy in-memory
            var finacQuery = (from s in values
                         where s.fiscal_year == fiscal_year && s.fiscal_month == fiscal_month && s.period_version == version
                         select s).ToList();

            var dimQuery = (from s in finacQuery
                         select s);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> dim in MainRibbon.dimensions)
            {
                    var dimLeaves = this.GetType().GetProperty(dim.Key).GetValue(this, null);
                    if (dimLeaves != null)
                    {
                        var leafList = this.ParseTreeDimensions(dimLeaves.ToString(), dim.Value);

                        // this has no impact on ToList() later down. dim.key is equal to, for example "business_unit"
                        dimQuery.Where(s => leafList.Contains(s.GetType().GetProperty(dim.Key).Name));
                    }
            }
            var test = dimQuery.ToList();
        }
    }
```

`dimQuery.Where(s => leafList.Contains(s.GetType().GetProperty(dim.Key).Name));` is where we would like a bit of help. After a good amount of searching, we haven't managed to find a pattern that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Where` doesn't *mutate* the query, it *returns a new query* that represents the original query but with an additional filter.  You're currently ignoring that return value and just throwing it away.

Comment: Good point. Tried that, now I'm getting a NullRef error. Tried .Name and .ToString() on leafList.Contains(s.GetType().GetProperty(dim.Key).ToString()

Comment: @SpaceSteak Then do whatever you'd do anytime you ever have a NRE; figure out what's null and either make sure it's not null, or add a check such that you only run the code when it's non-null.

Comment: Fair enough. :)  Thanks. Hopefully at least the logic makes sense.